# Can Mysql information_schema not be aligned with show create table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, information-schema

There seems to be data missing from information_schema. the `show create table` is different from information_schema.

when i run: `SHOW CREATE TABLE devicoserver.email_templates;`

I get 4 keys:

```
CREATE TABLE `email_templates` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email_templates_language_id_foreign` (`language_id`),
  KEY `email_templates_email_type_unique` (`email_type`),
  KEY `email_templates_subject_unique` (`subject`),
  CONSTRAINT `email_templates_language_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But, when I query the information schema it indicates that there are only 2 keys

```
    select 
         CONSTRAINT_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'email_templates' and CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'devicoserver';
```

`PRIMARY`, `id`
`email_templates_language_id_foreign`,`language_id`

Does this make sense, Can information_schema be different then the actuall table?
I know its actual because I have tried to create a key and i got exception that it is already existed.

Thanks

Comment: Try querying `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ` instead. i believe `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` shows the indexes what have been used when resolving queries.  "The KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table describes which key columns have constraints. " it says in the documentation don't know if thats wrong..

Comment: @RaymondNijland same thing... isn't that odd? thanks

Comment: The information_schema is never out of sync with other `SHOW` commands, because many of those `SHOW` commands are internally run as queries against the information_schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should query `information_schema`.`statistics`

e.g.

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX) 
FROM `information_schema`.`statistics` 
WHERE table_schema = 'dbname' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' 
GROUP BY INDEX_NAME 
ORDER BY INDEX_NAME ASC;
```

Comment: That was working.  can you explain why not using the tables `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`? thanks

Comment: As  @Raymond-Nijland was hinting referential_constraints is about Foreign Keys, key_column_usage is about columns that have constraints hence you see PK as well. The Statistics tells you about all INDEXES (remember PK is an index, FK require an index).